# Drawing a large number of lines quickly on google map in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps

I have a large number of points which I want to connect them together discontinuously. I can do this using
`googleMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions)` inside a for loop. But it's too time consuming.

If I use `polylineOptions.addAll` , The app would be very fast, but this method connects all the points together respectively. How can I connect these points but with some discontinuity in the resulted line?

Answer (score 0):

I personally do not see any use of a polyline that would be discontinuous. The whole point of it is connecting the "dots". Try and break your lat/lon locations collection into different lists depending on where you'd like to break the poly. Then simply add them to the map at the end.

Comment: Thank you, but I need to draw a large number of lines which each of them consist of only two points. How can I do this in an efficient way?